# Speeding up iabbrev setup?

Tags: performance, vim, abbreviation

I added a lot of `iabbrev` rules (~15K), and now vim takes 6 seconds to start (5.8 seconds is the abbreviations). Is there a way to speed up initialization?

Answer (score 4):

Posting your abbreviations somewhere would probably help us help you. Anyway, here are a few shots in the dark…

### Group filetype-specific abbreviations in dedicated ftplugins.

Say you have 50 or so abbreviations for JavaScript, you could group all those abbreviations in:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim
```

Doing that for every targeted language will significantly improve your startup time.

### Consider using a snippet expansion plugin.

The original [SnipMate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim), its more modern [fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) and its even more modern alternative [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) are all more powerful and battle-tested alternatives to abbreviations. If your abbreviations are programming-related, snippets are **the** way to go.

### Use dictionary completion.

The solutions above imply programming-related abbreviations but you may use them because you need to insert many field-specific words.

In such a situation, you could leverage dictionary completion.

1. Put all your words, each one on its own line, in a single file:

   ```
    ~/mydictionary
   ```
2. Put this line in your `~/.vimrc`:

   ```
    set dictionary+=~/mydictionary
   ```
3. Complete words with `<C-x><C-k>`.

See `:help ins-completion` and `:help 'dictionary'`.

--- edit ---

Here is why I asked for your abbreviations : you should be able to shorten the list to a hundred or so by generalizing a lot of your rules while keeping the specific ones that can't be generalized:

```
iabbrev ør oer
iabbrev ØR OER
iabbrev år aar
iabbrev ÅR AAR
```

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer. Not sure why you want to look at the abbrevs, but here they are: https://gist.github.com/simendsjo/abb975f8f0f13ca89a59. Regarding your suggestions: 1) augroup: I pretty much do this already. I only load these on the 'mail' filetype. 2) snippet: I use snippets for programming related completions, but this doesn't work here. I want them to be corrected always and not require a keybinding to do so. 3) dictionary: Same reason as 2) - requires pressing additional keys.

Comment: Please, see my edit. Also, an ftplugin is not the same as an augroup at all.

Comment: I doubt it's easy to generalize this.. Both `ør` and `oer` are valid in many contexts, which is why entire words are needed. And iabbrev won't match part of words, only complete words, thus `iabbrev ør oer` won't match `bør` (not that it should as both `bør` and `boer`  are valid words - it's impossible to get a perfect match).